# What is an Interface and when and how would one properly implement it? C#

Tags: c#, interface

I would like to know in general, but this question came up when I was trying to use IWMPMedia (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd563397(v=vs.85).aspx) which is an Interface. I was unable to use it in the normal object sense where I could instantiate it with the "new" keyword.

Comment: You should be able to get it from Windows Media player SDK, one of the methods should return IWMPMedia.

Comment: Thank you. I downloaded the Windows Media Player SDK which contains the the WMPLib namespace which has TONS of properties, methods, classes and other stuff that are all named poorly and have no documentation so I found it difficult to use. I was mostly asking for a general description of an Interface and how to use it.

Comment: What is with the downvotes? I thought the reason these StackExchange sites were created so when someone would google a programming question, it would be the top result as opposed to pay sites like EggHeadCafe. Yes I understand there are tons of documentation out there on this, I just figured I was doing a favor by asking this question here to increase the sites popularity.

Comment: some people will normally downvote you if you ask a question that could be easily googled. Some don't. Don't let it bother you though.

Comment: Downvote - you lose 2 reps, upvote you gain 10 reps. Your questions would have to garner greater than a 5:1 ratio of downvotes:upvotes to have lower your reps.

Although, I generally agree this question would best be answered by a quick google search; A quick google of "c# interface" yielded this article from MSDN http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/87d83y5b(v=vs.80).aspx

All that said, Hans Passant actually answers the question quite nicely.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IWMPMedia is a COM interface.  You get its declaration by adding a reference to c:\windows\system32\wmp.dll

COM interfaces don't behave very much like C# interfaces.  You can *never* create an instance of a C# interface with the *new* keyword.  But you can with a COM interface.  But not IWMPMedia, you get an instance of it by using one of the other interface methods.  Like IWMPPlayList.Item or IWMPCore.currentMedia.  The programming guide for Windows Media Player is [available here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd563069%28v=VS.85%29.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

An interface contains only the signatures of methods, properties, events or indexers. A class or struct that implements the interface must implement the members of the interface that are specified in the interface definition.

Reference: [MSDN C# Programming Guide.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173156.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

An interface is a contract that a class may implement.  This contract will define certain properties/ methods that all classes implementing that interface must contain.